# What's a 2×4 ultra clock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, terminology

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fcDWdUOLlI), the uploaders describe a mechanism to "automate" the mining of trees by filling blocks around and above tree you mine with air, while accelerating the speed at which "random ticks happen". At 0:59, the video mentions that the contraption is powered by a "2×4 ultra clock."

What's a so-called "2×4 ultra clock"? The weird thing is that the actual enclosed by the command blocks quite clearly is 2×2×1...

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

They meant 2x2.

What they call "Ultra clock" is also known as a fill clock: one command block does a `/fill` command with redstone blocks, another one does one with a different kind of block (e.g. stone). The rest of the command blocks will now get activated 20 times per second (each game tick).

The `/fill` command is currently only available in the snapshots.

Comment: Schematics, bitte? :)

Comment: Where should I upload that? Temporarily here: http://static.l3vi.de/Fill-Clock.schematic